# Why these (error) messages?

Tags: streams, message-coding, error-tracking

Testing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9097270/618728) I used:

```
stream = OpenWrite["A:\\out.txt"];

Block[{$Messages = stream},
  Mod[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
]
```

and I was surprised to find that the contents of `out.txt` read:

> ```
> Intersection::normal: 
>    Nonatomic expression expected at position \[NoBreak]\!\(\*StyleBox[2
>     , "MT"]\)\[NoBreak] in \[NoBreak]\!\(\*StyleBox[
>     Intersection[{StandardForm, TraditionalForm}, FormatType]
>     , "MT"]\)\[NoBreak]. >>
>
> Intersection::normal: 
>    Nonatomic expression expected at position \[NoBreak]\!\(\*StyleBox[2
>     , "MT"]\)\[NoBreak] in \[NoBreak]\!\(\*StyleBox[
>     Intersection[{StandardForm, TraditionalForm}, FormatType]
>     , "MT"]\)\[NoBreak]. >>
>
> Intersection::normal: 
>    Nonatomic expression expected at position \[NoBreak]\!\(\*StyleBox[2
>     , "MT"]\)\[NoBreak] in \[NoBreak]\!\(\*StyleBox[
>     Intersection[{StandardForm, TraditionalForm}, FormatType]
>     , "MT"]\)\[NoBreak]. >>
>
> General::stop: Further output of \[NoBreak]\!\(\*StyleBox[Intersection::normal
>     , "MT"]\)\[NoBreak] will be suppressed during this calculation. >>
>
> Options::optnf: 
>    \[NoBreak]\!\(\*StyleBox[FormatType
>     , "MT"]\)\[NoBreak] is not a known option for \[NoBreak]\!\(\*StyleBox[
>     Intersection[OutputStream[A:\out.txt, 12], 
>      {OutputStream[stdout, 1], OutputStream[stderr, 2], 
>       OutputStream[A:\out.txt, 12], stdout, stderr}], "MT"]\)\[NoBreak]. >>
>
> Options::optnf: 
>    \[NoBreak]\!\(\*StyleBox[FormatType
>     , "MT"]\)\[NoBreak] is not a known option for \[NoBreak]\!\(\*StyleBox[
>     Intersection[OutputStream[A:\out.txt, 12], 
>      {OutputStream[stdout, 1], OutputStream[stderr, 2], 
>       OutputStream[A:\out.txt, 12], stdout, stderr}], "MT"]\)\[NoBreak]. >>
>
> Options::optnf: 
>    \[NoBreak]\!\(\*StyleBox[FormatType
>     , "MT"]\)\[NoBreak] is not a known option for \[NoBreak]\!\(\*StyleBox[
>     Intersection[OutputStream[A:\out.txt, 12], 
>      {OutputStream[stdout, 1], OutputStream[stderr, 2], 
>       OutputStream[A:\out.txt, 12], stdout, stderr}], "MT"]\)\[NoBreak]. >>
>
> General::stop: Further output of \[NoBreak]\!\(\*StyleBox[Options::optnf
>     , "MT"]\)\[NoBreak] will be suppressed during this calculation. >>
>
> Intersection::heads: 
>    Heads \[NoBreak]\!\(\*StyleBox[List
>     , "MT"]\)\[NoBreak] and \[NoBreak]\!\(\*StyleBox[OutputStream
>     , "MT"]\)\[NoBreak] at positions \[NoBreak]\!\(\*StyleBox[2
>     , "MT"]\)\[NoBreak] and \[NoBreak]\!\(\*StyleBox[1
>     , "MT"]\)\[NoBreak] are expected to be the same. >>
>
> Intersection::heads: 
>    Heads \[NoBreak]\!\(\*StyleBox[List
>     , "MT"]\)\[NoBreak] and \[NoBreak]\!\(\*StyleBox[OutputStream
>     , "MT"]\)\[NoBreak] at positions \[NoBreak]\!\(\*StyleBox[2
>     , "MT"]\)\[NoBreak] and \[NoBreak]\!\(\*StyleBox[1
>     , "MT"]\)\[NoBreak] are expected to be the same. >>
>
> Intersection::heads: 
>    Heads \[NoBreak]\!\(\*StyleBox[List
>     , "MT"]\)\[NoBreak] and \[NoBreak]\!\(\*StyleBox[OutputStream
>     , "MT"]\)\[NoBreak] at positions \[NoBreak]\!\(\*StyleBox[2
>     , "MT"]\)\[NoBreak] and \[NoBreak]\!\(\*StyleBox[1
>     , "MT"]\)\[NoBreak] are expected to be the same. >>
>
> General::stop: Further output of \[NoBreak]\!\(\*StyleBox[Intersection::heads
>     , "MT"]\)\[NoBreak] will be suppressed during this calculation. >>
>
> Mod::argt: \[NoBreak]\!\(\*StyleBox[Mod
>     , "MT"]\)\[NoBreak] called with \[NoBreak]\!\(\*StyleBox[5
>     , "MT"]\)\[NoBreak] arguments; \[NoBreak]\!\(\*StyleBox[2
>     , "MT"]\)\[NoBreak] or \[NoBreak]\!\(\*StyleBox[3
>     , "MT"]\)\[NoBreak] arguments are expected. >>
> ```

I expected only the last message.  This looks like the result of a misconfiguration or Style Sheet problem but I don't know what it is.

Do others get these messages?  If yes, what is the explanation?  If not, what might I have done to cause this?

Comment: You should re-read the usage message for `$Messages` *very* carefully.

Comment: @Brett actually I didn't read it at all; I trusted Szabolcs.  I blame him!

Comment: To clarify a bit the somewhat cryptic answer of @Brett  - `$Messages` point to a *channel*, which can be a *list* of streams, but not a single stream without a list around it.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Don't answer in comments!

Comment: @Brett Did not indend to. This was *your* answer, I just commented on it :). Why don't you put this as an answer?

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I don't think there's any rule against *hinting* in comments...

Comment: @Brett Well then, I was *hinting* on your hint, I guess.

Comment: @Bett & Leonid, I am glad you both are having fun with my bonehead question. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The documentation for `$Messages` clearly states:

> $Messages gives the ***list*** of files and pipes to which message output is sent.

Therefore `Block[{$Messages = {stream}}, ... ]` is the correct syntax.