# What is the "proper" way of multiplying a list of vectors by a matrix? Why Map does not work?

Tags: matrix, map

I am an absolute newbie with *Mathematica*, so please forgive me if this is stupid, but for the life of me I can't solve this.

Suppose I have a list of vectors $b_{1...n}$ and a square matrix $A$ and I want $Ab_1, Ab_2, ... Ab_n$.

$\mathbf{Ab_i} = \begin{pmatrix}
a & b  \\
p & q  \\
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
x \\
y 
\end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix}
ax + by \\
px + qy  \\
\end{pmatrix}\,,
$

Let them be:

```
A := {{1, 2} {3, 4}};
b = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}};
```

If I just do

```
A * b
```

Mathematica complains about `objects of unequal length` - I guess it is assuming (resaonably) that I want to multiply a $2\times2$ matrix by a $2\times3$ matrix.

My second choice is:

```
Map[#1*A &, b]
```

This doesn't work either.

```
Thread::tdlen: "Objects of unequal length in {1,2} {{3,8}} cannot be combined.
Thread::tdlen: "Objects of unequal length in {3,4} {{3,8}} cannot be combined.
Thread::tdlen: "Objects of unequal length in {5,6} {{3,8}} cannot be combined.
```

So, what is the most "Mathematica-like" to get $Ab_1, Ab_2, ... Ab_n$ (and why doesn't `Map` work)?

Comment: you missed `,` betwen vectors in defenition of `A`

Comment: That's a **definition** of inner product, so just `.` and a missing comma.

Comment: I am an idiot, sorry. The whole comma thing (and the fact that we don't usually call it "dot product" in my language) led me to brainfart spectacularly.

Comment: Foolish questions happen.  [Here is one of mine.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1118/121) :^)  Eventually this will be deleted in routine maintenance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `.` for vector and matrix multiplication.

The following works:

```
Map[A.#1 &, b]
Map[#1.A &, b]
```

Your definition of `A` misses a comma by the way.

Comment: Gosh. I didn't notice the comma at all. Thanks.